# What attributes of object Zope publishes?

Tags: url-routing, zope

I could do: `app.restrictedTraverse('/zport/dmd/version')` which gives me `'Zenoss 4.2.4'`, but when I do the same in the browser, it gives me

> Site error. An error was encountered while publishing this resource.
>   The requested resource does not exist.

For some other values or functions on `dmd` object it works. How do I debug "does not exists" error, and how mapping from url to object in Zope works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Citing the ZPublisher.BaseRequest.DefaultPublishTraverse.publishTraverse](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/blob/master/src/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py#L139):

```
    # Ensure that the object has a docstring, or that the parent
    # object has a pseudo-docstring for the object. Objects that
    # have an empty or missing docstring are not published.
    doc = getattr(subobject, '__doc__', None)
    if not doc:
        raise Forbidden(
            "The object at %s has an empty or missing " \
            "docstring. Objects must have a docstring to be " \
            "published." % URL
            )

    # Hack for security: in Python 2.2.2, most built-in types
    # gained docstrings that they didn't have before. That caused
    # certain mutable types (dicts, lists) to become publishable
    # when they shouldn't be. The following check makes sure that
    # the right thing happens in both 2.2.2+ and earlier versions.

    if not typeCheck(subobject):
        raise Forbidden(
            "The object at %s is not publishable." % URL
            )
```

`typeCheck` regards this types as forbidden:

```
        ('NoneType', 'IntType', 'LongType', 'FloatType', 'StringType',
         'BufferType', 'TupleType', 'ListType', 'DictType', 'XRangeType',
         'SliceType', 'EllipsisType', 'UnicodeType', 'CodeType',
         'TracebackType', 'FrameType', 'DictProxyType', 'BooleanType',
         'ComplexType')
```